# Ionic 3 iOS 11 Multiple Styling Issues

Tags: ios, css, sass, ionic3, iphone-x

*Note: this is not a screen size issue, so do not mark this as a duplicate of the iOS 11 Ionic 3 migration questions.*

### Problem

After following the Ionic 3 documentation for [updating apps to iOS 11](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/) and for iPhone X, my once-neatly-styled UI has been, for lack of a better phrase, **messed up**. I am baffled as to whether this is an issue related to the Ionic Team increasing the viewport widths and heights tremendously as to shrink many of my **`vw`- and `vh`-unit** measurements.

The general trend, however, is that elements I have set the height and width for manually appear much more visible than those that are sized via Ionic's generic CSS.

**The source of the error is likely this line that I have in my `index.html` file (note `viewport-fit:cover`):**

```
<meta name="viewport" content-type="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Issue on iPhone X (Similar on Other Platforms)

---

[image: iPhone X Problem]

---

### Expected Result

Expected Result on iPhone 8 and Earlier Devices

---

[image: iPhone 8 Expected Result]

---

My company's beta testing is in a few days, so any help will be appreciated sincerely.

---

For reference, this is how a network error appears on the iPhone X.

[image: Network Error]

### Updates

1. I also realized that I can zoom in and out of my viewport, even though I set: `user-scalable=no`.

Comment: It would probably help to actually include the *code* that's causing the problem. What does the HTML and CSS look like for the side menu?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'd already included the one line of code I added that caused the problem. It must be left in my code in order for the application to scale for iPhone X and if I could remove it, I would. As you can tell, the side menu is not the only issue. The feed is just as improperly styled. It is an issue with the entire application's styling.